# Enable header filters in excel export using jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to enable to filters to the excel top row / header file which is generated from table data using Jquery Datatables library.

I've followed this tutorial https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html and it works great and generated excel file looks like below.

[image]

As you can see in that pic, there are no filters to the top row. I know that we can enable filters in the excel file after opening. But I'm trying to do it when the excel file gets generated.

So, the exported excel file should like below.

[image]

You can see highlights in red circle with filters.

So Just wondering if it's possible and any suggestions about how to accomplish that would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can enables filters automatically by changing the excel file schema in the file buttons.html5.js.

In the buttons.html5.js file, you can find the below code.

```
// Excel - Pre-defined strings to build a minimal XLSX file
var excelStrings = {
    "_rels/.rels": '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">\
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/>\
</Relationships>',

    "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels": '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">\
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet1.xml"/>\
</Relationships>',

    "[Content_Types].xml": '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">\
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>\
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>\
    <Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>\
    <Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/>\
    <Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>\
</Types>',

    "xl/workbook.xml": '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">\
    <fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="5" lowestEdited="5" rupBuild="24816"/>\
    <workbookPr showInkAnnotation="0" autoCompressPictures="0"/>\
    <bookViews>\
        <workbookView xWindow="0" yWindow="0" windowWidth="25600" windowHeight="19020" tabRatio="500"/>\
    </bookViews>\
    <sheets>\
        <sheet name="__SHEET_NAME__" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/>\
    </sheets>\
</workbook>',

    "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml": '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">\
    <sheetData>\
        __DATA__\
    </sheetData>\
</worksheet>'
};
```

You have to update the above object as below.

```
excelStrings["xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"] = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"><sheetData>__DATA__</sheetData><autoFilter ref="A1:g1"/></worksheet>';
```

The only difference is that we appended **`<autoFilter ref="A1:g1"/>`**.

Please note that ref="A1:G1" are the columns to which this auto filter will be enabled.

This is how I solved my issue of enabling auto filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the Datatable from the existing "buttons" property.

```
buttons: [ {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        autoFilter: true,
        sheetName: 'Sheet Name'
    } ]
```

- https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelAutoFilter.html